# CouchDB - prevent unauthorized reads

Tags: couchdb

CouchDB has a mechanism in place to prevent unauthorized writes.

Can it also prevent unauthorized reads?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, CouchDB can prevent unauthorized reads. Unfortunately, it is slightly less straightforward.

Imagine a secret auction application. You bid $20 and I bid $10; each bid in a couch document. Couch lets us read our own bid documents but no others. *However*, there is a map-reduce view showing the average. I load the view and see that the average is $15, so I conclude that your bid is $20 and I have broken the security policy. **View output can leak some or all of a document's information. It is not feasible to enforce security at the document level. That is why read access is at the database level.**

I know, it sucks. But that is the only correct, scalable answer.

This is part of the reason the Couch philosophy is to create many databases—even one (or more!) per user. Read permission to a database is set in the `readers` value of the database `_security` object. (Note, the field [readers was renamed to members](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/commit/444919faf5ab8e7a9aba1043a428e2539dd5b66c#diff-5) in CouchDB trunk because it also specifies who may write to the DB.)

The technique works like this:

1. Create a database for each user. It will hold all documents the user may read. Add the user (or the user's role) to the `_security` object.
2. In the master database, create a filter function which implements the read policy. (It could share code with `validate_doc_update`.)
3. Replicate from the master database to the user's database with `?filter=my_filter_function`.
4. Allow the user to load (or replicate from) their database.

Of course, this is all for a pure Couch application, where users access Couch directly. If you have a middle layer (MVC controller, or just a reverse HTTP proxy), then you can enforce policy there, between the user and the couch. But **be careful**. For example, a `_show` function or a `_rewrite` rule might allow a user to load a view or document despite your policy.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on how _show and _rewrite could bite me? Also, how do I avoid race conditions like "unfriend someone -> upload photo" and being 100% sure that the unfriended person can never see that photo?

Comment: Well, suppose you have a reverse proxy that allows/denies access per document per user based on the URL. Later, you add a new feature using a _list function and all _list queries are allowed by the proxy. A user might figure out how to use the _list to see documents he shouldn't. Similarly, a _rewrite rule may provide a way to see documents without the normal `/db/doc_id` path. So you have to be *very* sure that your proxy has no holes.

Comment: Your second question is more about **revoking** read access than **granting** read access. I propose you ask a fresh question ("How to revoke read access in the CouchDB security model"). I'll take a shot at an answer if I can!

Comment: creating a database for each user would require the application to know the server admin credentials AFAIK. Isn't that a risk considering that the same credentials can be used to wipe out all the databases running on a cluster?