# access session information from couchdb views

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I'm new to couchdb/couchapp. I'm wondering if it's possible to access _session information from couchdb views. For example:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.username == session.userCtx.name) {
    emit(doc.username, doc);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question! The answer is **no** and it's important to understand why.

The policy about which users may see what data is done at the **database level**, not the *document* or *view* level. It sounds odd however it makes sense in the long-run.

The function that *does* have access to the session is **filter functions**. You can use those to create private databases per-user with all the documents they may read.

I wrote more answers about read permissions in a question about [_all_docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953259/can-i-restrict-unauthenticated-users-from-accessing-all-docs/4999893#4999893), and also about [CouchDB read permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730621/couchdb-prevent-unauthorized-reads/4731514#4731514).

Comment: Thank you @jhs It makes sense. I think I'll aim to provision new database per user. Cheers!